# How cookbooks are stored on the Chef Server

Tags: chef-infra

On the Chef Server how are Cookbooks stored? Are they stored as folders in some sort of a hierarchy, as a compressed file or serialized on to database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are stored with [bookshelf](https://github.com/opscode/bookshelf) which is (quoting the readme)

Bookshelf is an S3 API compatible object store.

I'm talking about the Open Source Chef Server, as far as I know the Entreprise Chef server (hosted or private) use the same architecture, the main change is the WebUI and the addons for Entreprise chef.

Comment: They are all pretty much the same. There are subtle differences in the way objects are stored in Enterprise Chef because of ACLs, but yea.